# How do I duplicate the formatting of a Web Part?

Tags: web-part, tasks, formatting

I'm building a page with tasks for my team and I can't figure out how to copy the Task Web Part formatting to each of the other team members.
At the moment I ams doing this by hand setting:

- Web Part

  - No Toolbaar
- Appearance

  - Title and Bordered
- List Modify View

  - 1 %complete
  - 2 Task Status
  - 3 Due Date
  - 4 Task Name (linked to item
    with edit menu)

How do I do this automatically for all 30 Task web parts in one go?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way.

You can do this using PowerShell. Use PowerShell to get the web part properties and set it based on already created one.